# Efficient way to import data from one system to another system?

Tags: java, mysql, data-import

I have two different java web applications. Web app 1 has millions of user data including profile pictures etc. Now i need to import this data in another application i.e. Web app 2.

In Web app 2, I will be dong some processing on the data. One way we are thinking is export all data from web app 1 into csv or excel file and then upload this csv into Web app 2. URL's of the pictures will be also be sent this way. So only url will be imported and not the actual picture itself.

The other way we could think of doing this in the backend only. As this is just one time activity e.g. We will freeze the web app 1, so we will know the data to import then may be we can just run query in the database itself and import the required data.

We dont need to import all fields, just the data we need for processing in the web app 2. So, if Web app 1 has 50 columns, we might need only 10 columns in web app2.

So, are any of these good way to do this or is there any better way?

Comment: mysqldump comes to mind

Comment: [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load).